# Converting units of standard deviation

Tags: probability, variance, standard-deviation

celsius=5/9(fahrenheit− 32)

if the standard deviation of a random sample containing 14 people is 0.9 degrees farenheit, what's the variance in celsius?

I have tried 5/9(0.18-32) but I get a negative number for variance which is obviously wrong. I used 0.18 because 0.9^2=0.18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shifting the data does not change the deviations at all. So the subtraction is completely irrelevant to this problem.

Multiplying the data by $\frac59$ multiplies the standard deviation by $\frac59$.

Once you know the standard deviation in Celsius, it's not difficult to find the variance.

Comment: I'm still confused as to why I don't need to subtract.

Comment: Variance measures the data's squared deviation from the mean.  Now in case you shift the data, the deviation between the shifted data and the shifted mean remain the same.  (In case the data are scaled by some factor all deviations will be scaled by this factor and the variance changes by the factor's square.)

Comment: @User Because the deviations for the data $1,2,3,4,5$ is exactly the same as the deviations for the data $11,12,13,14,15$, is exactly the same as the deviations for the data $33,34,35,36,37$.

Comment: Should I change the standard deviation to variance before multiplying by 5/9?

Comment: @User You could. But then also remember that multiplying the data by $\frac59$ multiplies the variance by $\frac{25}{81}$.